# NFS Kernel Server active but exited status

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, nfs

I setup a NFS on an Ubuntu machine which was working for the better part of a week. For some maintenance work, the admin team had to reboot the machine and now the service has seemingly stopped.

The output of `systemctl status nfs-kernel-server`:

```
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-08-19 14:07:18 UTC; 2s ago
Process: 79833 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 79826 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 79824 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 79867 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 79865 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 79867 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 19 14:07:18 AZVGTOOPS05 systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Aug 19 14:07:18 AZVGTOOPS05 systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

Any ideas on how to fix/debug this issue? The machine OS is Ubuntu 18.04